# What's the point of blessed in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
[root@ ~]$ perl -e "print 1 if blessed $a;"
1
[root@ ~]$ perl -e "print 1 if blessed $c;"
1
[root@ ~]$ perl -e "print 1 if blessed $cee;"
1
```

It seems always `true`,the version is `5.8.8`.

**UPDATE**

I'm not running as `root`, it's CHANGED by me for the sake of privacy:)

Comment: Running code when you don't know what it does as *root* is probably not the best of ideas!

Comment: What did you *expect* to see instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does Perl's "bless" do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392135/what-exactly-does-perls-bless-do)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill ,is there anything `not` blessed?

Comment: Well, a new hash reference `{}` shouldn't be blessed...

Comment: What is this "`blessed`" you speak of?  [The Perl documentation has nothing on it.](http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=blessed)  Do you mean "[`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean [`blessed`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html)? You probably want to load the function first:

```
perl -MScalar::Util=blessed -e "print 1 if blessed $a;"
```

otherwise your `blessed` is just bareword (string), which is obviously true.

Comment: How can `blessed $a;` be interpreted as bareword?

Comment: Bareword is not taken as string, as `print test` doesn't output `test`.

Comment: @asker - `print test` is not good example, as it is parsed to `print test $_` (using test as filehandle). Try `print STDOUT test`. But anyway, in your case `blessed` is not bareword, because of surrounding context (it is interpreted as `$a->blessed` when blessed is not defined)

Comment: @asker, The shell interpolates an empty string for `$a`, so the code is just `print 1 if blessed `, which is the same as `print 1 if "blessed"` when strict is off.

Comment: @bvr, It is NOT interpreted as `$a->blessed`. That would result in a runtime error. See my message to asker.

Comment: @ikegami - sorry for confusion, on Windows it is and it indeed result in runtime error.

Comment: @bvr On my instance of Strawberry Perl (5.12) I get no runtime exception - it prints 1. Perhaps it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: @Robert P, It has nothing to do with the OS, but the shell. @bvr is using `cmd` and I'm guessing you are using `bash`.

Comment: @ikegami nope, I was using cmd on windows.  Strawberry Perl is a windows only distribution :)

Comment: @Robert P, No you weren't. Not if you ran the program you said you ran and got the output you said you got. Something you said isn't true.

Comment: @Robert P, Furthermore, I never said you weren't using Windows. If you're on Windows, you're surely using cygwin's `bash`, not `cmd`. Although saying you're on Windows when using cygwin is rather disingenuous, since cygwin is a unix emulation layer.

Comment: @Robert P - I am using quite recent AS perl 5.12.4. When you just run `perl -MO=Deparse -e "print 1 if blessed $a;"` within `cmd` shell, you get `print 1 if $a->blessed;`. Obviously `$a` is not interpolated by the shell.

Comment: @bvr: Interesting; now I can reproduce it with Strawberry Perl 5.12.2.  Dunno what's going on. :)  I think the real answer is: non-strict Perl is insane and should be avoided.

Answer (score 10):

`blessed` is not a keyword in Perl. You are using double quotes in your shell command, so the variables (`$a`, `$c`, etc.) are from your shell's environment, they are not Perl variables.
Since these environment variables are probably empty, you are essentially executing the script

```
print 1 if blessed ;
```

When used like this, `blessed` is just a *bareword* string and always evaluates to true. What you have done is not much difference from running

```
$ perl -e 'print 1 if foo'
```

Comment: Oops, did not occured to me. Because of quotes, I assumed OP is on Windows. Good point.

Comment: or to make it even clearer, it's like running `perl -e "print 1 if 'blessed'"`

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you need to load the module before using the method. Also, if you had used `perl -we` instead of `perl -e`, you would probably not have asked this question.

For me, with `perl -we`, I get this warning:

```
Can't call method "blessed" without a package or object reference at -e line 1.
```